# PowerShell and cmd returning different results

Tags: powershell, cmd

Why are these returning different results? What am I missing about the cmd command?

```
PS C:\src\t\cad> Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path $Env:ProgramFiles -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object

Count    : 17381
```

And from cmd.exe:

```
10:28:18.87  C:\src\t\cad
C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path '"%ProgramFiles%"' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ^| Measure-Object"

Count    : 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of the caret `^`. You are trying to escape the pipe `|` for the command interpreter, but you don't need to because it's already in a quoted string, so it doesn't get interpreted and gets sent directly to PowerShell.

As a result, PowerShell sees this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path 'C:\Program Files' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ^| Measure-Object
```

So why doesn't that work?

Parameters to PowerShell commands are separated by spaces, and when a parameter is not named specifically it's treated positionally, if possible.

Let's look at a simpler example to demonstrate:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . ^
```

Similarly you'll see no output, but with a trace, we can see why:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { Get-ChildItem -Path . ^ } -PSHost
```

> ```
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Get-ChildItem]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [.] to parameter [Path]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.String to
> System.String[]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [String],
> parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Get-ChildItem]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [^] to parameter [Filter]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [^] to param [Filter] SUCCESSFUL
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object:
> [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildDynamicParameters]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Get-ChildItem]
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
> DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
> ```

That caret was bound positionally to the `-Filter` parameter. <s>It seems the filtering is rather lenient in that it doesn't care if the value is nonsense; I guess it just treats it as non-matching and doesn't throw an error</s>.

Per [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s comment:

> `^` is technically a valid filename, and `-Filter` accepts filename
>   (patterns); thus, if you had a file literally named `^`, it would be
>   matched. Using illegal-in-a-filename characters (which vary by
>   platform) does break, though the helpfulness of the error messages
>   varies.

So what you have with `-Filter ^` is a filter that never matches, hence 0 results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is suppressing an error in the first command so then nothing is being passed down the pipeline to `Measure-Object`.

Testing this on PSCore I get:

```
pwsh -command "get-process ^| measure-object"
get-process : Cannot find a process with the name "^".
Count    : 0
```

But removing the '^' character:

```
bash-3.2$ pwsh -command "get-process | measure-object"
Count    : 318
```

So I assume that's the same for Windows PowerShell.  Try without the ^

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path '"%ProgramFiles%"' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object"
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it is not because of `-ErrorAction`. It does work without the caret, but it is unrelated to `-ErrorAction`.

Comment: To add to @lit's comment: even if you don't silence errors, _error_ output is never sent through the _pipeline_ (unless you redirect it explicitly with `2>&1`), but if you omit `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, errors would print to the _console_ (terminal).
The advice to remove the `^` is good, but the `-ErrorAction`-related part of your answer is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658600/45375) with the `cmd.exe` perspective:

- In `cmd.exe`, `^` only serves as the escape character in *unquoted* strings.
- Inside *double-quoted* strings (`"..."`):

  - the *only* character that needs escaping is `"` itself.
  - `^` has no special meaning and is retained as-is.

Given that the `|` character you intend to pass through to PowerShell is inside `"..."`, you therefore need not - and must not - use `^` to escape it.